# How to wait callback inside recursive function

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, recursion, callback, wait

I have a recursive function:

```
let main = () => {
  ftp(_defaultPath, _start, (file, doc, name) => {
    parser(file, doc, name)
  })
}
```

The parser function:

```
module.exports = async function (file, doc, name) {
    await funcOne(file, doc)
    await funcTwo(file, doc, name)
    await funcThree(file, doc, name)
}
```

The callback its called inside the recursive function multiple times:

```
async function myFuntion(path, name, callback) {
   ...
   callback(file, doc, files[p][1])
   ...
}
```

The problem is I want to wait when i do callback like:

```
async function myFuntion(path, name, callback) {
   ...
   await callback(file, doc, files[p][1])
   ... next lines need to wait to finish callback
}
```

I trying to find how to do that.

It's possible to do that? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done on this way:

I edit my main function with async inside ftp function:

```
let main = () => {
  ftp(_defaultPath, _start, async (file, doc, name) => {
    await parser(file, doc, name)
  })
}
```

I added the promise to parser function like that:

```
module.exports = function (file, doc, name) {
    return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            await funcOne(file, doc)
            await funcTwo(file, doc, name)
            await funcThree(file, doc, name)
        } catch(e) {
            return reject(e)
        }
        return resolve()
    }
}
```

Inside the recursive function I do the await.

```
await callback(file, doc, files[p][1])
```

Now waits as expected.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> It's possible to do that?

Yeah, it's possible to use `await` but for this to work:

```
await callback(file, doc, files[p][1])
```

your `callback()` needs to return a promise. From your code it's not clear that it does.

Comment: Thanks! Just i found the solution :D